# Req.body is empty object when performing a put request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, express, put

I am performing a PUT request from frontend to backend, where the backend function updates my Firestore database. The function works fine in itself (can be called via postman etc) but not from the frontend, because req.body will always be an empty object. I have of course examined many other similar cases, have added a bunch of headers and other things but none of it has solved my problem. This is my backend code:

```
router.put('/:id/results', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log("Updating results...") //THIS IS LOGGED
        console.log(req.body)              // THIS LOGS {}
        let hamsters = []
        console.log(req.params.id)          //LOGS ID
        let snapShots = await db.collection('hamsters').where("id", "==", parseInt(req.params.id)).get()
        snapShots.forEach(doc => {
            hamsters.push(doc.data())
        })
        if (req.body.wins == 1) {
            hamsters[0].wins++
            res.send(`${hamsters[0].name} now has ${hamsters[0].wins} wins!`)
        } else if (req.body.defeats == 1) {
            hamsters[0].defeats++
            res.send(`${hamsters[0].name} now has ${hamsters[0].defeats} defeats!`)
        } else {
            throw ("You must either increase wins or defeats by 1") //THIS IS LOGGED
        }
        hamsters[0].games++
        db.collection('hamsters').doc(req.params.id).set(hamsters[0])
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
})
```

My frontend function has two different methods depending on the outcome parameter, they look slightly different now only to illustrate that it doesn't seem to matter how I write the request. The function does not return anything at the moment since it only has to update the database.

```
export async function putBattleStats(hamsterID, outcome) {
    try {
        if (outcome === "win") {
            const response = await fetch(`/hamsters/${hamsterID}/results`,
                {
                    method: 'PUT', headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json/x-www-form-urlencoded" }, body: {
                        "hamsterID": JSON.stringify(hamsterID),
                        "wins": +1
                    }
                })
        } else if (outcome === "defeat") {
            const response = await fetch(`/hamsters/${hamsterID}/results`,
                {
                    method: 'PUT', body: {
                        "hamsterID": hamsterID,
                        "defeats": +1
                    }
                })
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error('Fetch failed because', e)
        return null
    }
}
```

Like I said, I have experimented with various headers, I have installed node-fetch, I have also put these lines in my server.js file:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    server.use(bodyParser.json())

    server.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        next();
    });
```

I just hope that I am missing something obvious.

Comment: In your backend code when you `throw` the error you're just logging it in the console. Maybe you want to send that to the frontend as well.

Comment: Perhaps, but I can view the error in the console anyway so it does not seem important.

Comment: Your issue was that you don't see anything in the frontend after sending the request, so just logging it alone won't send anything to the frontend. Error response is important.

Comment: No, the issue is that when the backend function recieves a request from the frontend, the body of that request is empty from the start.

Comment: Can you try what I suggested in my answer?

Comment: What does it matter if I log the same error message to the frontend? I am not very advanced at this so I can't afford to spend time on things that don't change anything.

Comment: I mean it's up to you to decide what your app does once you get an error. Anyway, you said that `req.body` is always empty so can you check my answer to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because you're not stringifying the entire body.

Try this:

```
const response = await fetch(`/hamsters/${hamsterID}/results`,
// change this URL
    {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        // this can just be 'application/json' in your case
        body: JSON.stringify({
            hamsterID: hamsterID,
            wins: 1
        })
    })
```

Comment: That sounded like a good idea, but sadly nothing changed.

Comment: @Zuzim - The URL is wrong, it should be something like `http://localhost:3000/hamsters/${hamsterID}/results`. Assuming your backend app is running in the localhost at the port 3000.

Comment: I am using a proxy server. All get requests to the backend work fine, and this put request also reaches the backend, but with an empty request.

Comment: @Zuzim - Oh, did you also try changing the header?